# Append .html extension with php

Tags: php, html

I am creating a search function that returns entries in my database.

I want to dynamically create a HTML page with the name of the entry in the database. I create the name; however, I can't append the `.html` extension to it.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  echo "<li>" . "<a href=".$filmName.".html\"> "   .$filmName . " </a></li>\n";
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You code will append `.html` to the link target, but not to the printed filename. Is this intended? You echo the file name twice, be sure you append the file extension to the right output. The value inside `href="..."` is not actually shown on the page.

Comment: I want to then be able to open the html file when you click on the link. At the moment it is creating a link without the .html extension, for example if i had an entry called lion, when i click the link it opens website/lion instead of website/lion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to get your escaped "'s in order

```
    echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"" . $filmName . ".html\"> " . $filmName . " </a></li>\n";
```

I've added an \" after the href